# Function doesn't add items to an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function but there is something I can't figure out

```
def function(l1,l2):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for e1 in la:
        for e2 in lb:
            if e1 < e2:
                list1.append(e1)
            elif e2 < e1:
                list2.append(e2)
    l1[:] = list1
    l2[:] = list2
```

but this function gives me no output.

This function should act this way:

```
function([1,2,3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,1,2,3])
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3]
```

My teacher told me that the last two lines in the function are necessary.

I have already tried to return the two lists or to print them, but I was told that the function just have to "modify" given lists.

Comment: What is your function supposed to do?

Comment: Tried to fix indentation. Hopefully didn't break your original version.

Comment: you have wrong names in definiton - it has to be `la, lb` instead of  `l1, l2` in  `def function(la, lb):` . And you have to create lists `l1`, `l2` (they can be even empty) before you run `function`

Comment: my function is supposed to compare the elements of the lists which are in the same position, then the function delete the element with the higher value.

Comment: i can give an example with strings:

Comment: function(['cat','dog','abac'),['dandy','annoying','cheer']):   gives --->              list1 = ['cat','abac'] list2 = ['annoying']

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is as follows. You need to assign the list to names before calling the function, so that you actually have the references to the list in your main scope. In your example, you simply redefine `l1` and `l2`. Try this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3]
function(l1, l2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function, even when corrected, does not produce the correct output.  Ask yourself:  how many times am I considering `l2[0]`?  Answer: `len(l1)` times!  What you want to do is `zip` the lists together to consider the first element of each list at the same time, then the second, etc

```
def keep_lesser(l1, l2):
    la = []
    lb = []
    for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
        if a < b:
            la.append(a)
        elif b < a:
            lb.append(b)
    l1[:] = la
    l2[:] = lb
```

This function doesn't return anything, but instead mutates, or changes, the two lists passed to it as inputs.

EDIT: Example Usage

```
>>first = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>second = [4,5,6,1,2,3]
>>keep_lesser(first, second)   <--note how this returns None
>>print(first)
[1, 2, 3]
>>print(second)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: _"does not product the correct output."_ - Did you mean _produce_? ;)

Comment: @leaf looks like i can't even 'product' correct sentences

Comment: if i write this down:

Comment: keep_lesser(['oana','capri','food'],['too','bologna','tirreno'])                      it doesn't show the modified lists, i don't know why

Comment: This function modifies the lists, but doesn't return them.  Assign the lists to variables, then pass those variables into the function.  The functions will change the value of the variables.  When you're calling it, you don't keep references to the lists around, so you can't see them after they have changed

Comment: could youu provide an example?

Comment: @mewtire example added.  You might benefit from researching the term "Pass by reference"

Comment: ahhh everything is clear now, i could't understand before because of my english. thanks you guys for the help, i really appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of your function are l1 and l2 not la and lb. You didn't put any return statement.

```
def function(l1,l2):
  list1 = []
  list2 = []
  for e1 in l1:
    for e2 in l2:
        if e1 < e2:
            list1.append(e1)
        elif e2 < e1:
            list2.append(e2)
  l1[:] = list1
  l2[:] = list2
  return l1,l2
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want to do - have a function that **prints** or a function that **returns** or a function that **changes** the existing lists.

If you want to print, then you're missing a:

```
print list1,list2
```

at the end instead of the copy lines (the `[:]` lines). If you want to change the lists given to the function, than what you did is fine:

```
l1[:]=list1
```

updates the list in place, so if you do:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2=[4,5,6,1,2,3]
function(l1,l2)
print l1,l2
```

You see the result. If you don't print, you won't see the result!
Finally you could return, so instead of the last two lines:

```
return list1,list2
```

so you can:

```
print function(1,2,3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,1,2,3])
```

**The problem of your first version**: you created two lists in the function, but did nothing with them. In any case you need a print statement to see the results of the call.

Note you posted some coding errors, check the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by other answers you switched `l1` and `l2` with `la` and `lb` and you should pass the function two lists previously assigned instead of list literals.

Other than that your function does not what you expect, you should iterate through the lists with an index like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [4,5,6,1,2,3]
def function(l1,l2):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        e1 = l1[i]
        e2 = l2[i]
        if e1 < e2:
            list1.append(e1)
        elif e2 < e1:
            list2.append(e2)
    l1[:] = list1
    l2[:] = list2

function(l1,l2)
print l1,l2
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: why if i wtrite

Comment: if i write function(['capri','milano','genoa'],['roma','linate','torino']) ,           why does the function not show me the modified lists?

Comment: Because you are passing the function two list literals which will be discarded after the function exits since they are not bound to any variable.
In order to use them afterwards you should assign them to a name like I've shown in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I see some mistake in your code:

```
for e1 in la:
for e2 in lb:
```

I guess it should be:

```
for e1 in l1:
for e2 in l2:
```